# Change the style and colour of scatterplots by two groups (one per style, another per color)

Tags: r, plot, grouping, data-visualization

I am trying to change the style of scatterplots depending on a vector, and their color depending on another vector. This is what I have done with the function "plot", but I fail miserably when I add the colour.

```
 windows(12, 8)
 plot(jitter(as.numeric(list$VECTOR,3)), 
 jitter(as.numeric(list$VECTOR,3)) , xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", 
 pch= c(19,1)[unclass(list$Country)], bg=cols,
 ylab ="babla",  xlab= "blabla")
```

As "cols" I have added one of these two options `cols<- ifelse(list$Leadership== "cabinet", "red", "black")` and`cols <- c("black", "red")[unclass(list$Leadership)]`, but I was not sucessfull. Also, I have changed the argument "bg" for "col", and I fail as well. Please, note that I do not want to use ggplot, ggplot2 nor xyplot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try storing your data in table and then using `ggplot2` to plot it.

Comment: Provide us with a reproducible example, please. Typically, something like `v1 = 1:10 ; plot(jitter(v1), jitter(v1), pch=rep(1:2, each=5), col=rep(c('red', 'blue','green','yellow','black'), 2))` would work. So if you correctly build a vector for `pch` and one for `col`, it should be all fine...

Comment: ok, the solution ````cols<- ifelse(list$Leadership== "cabinet", "red", "black")```` works, but only if the argument is  within "c(ifelse...)" :)